# Is there a canonical way to print a stack trace in perl 6?

Tags: debugging, raku

In perl 5, I would use any of the Carp functions. In perl 6, searching was no help, and the [trace pragma](https://docs.perl6.org/programs/01-debugging#trace_pragma) will print all stacks, not just the one I want. I could only use the old hack of throwing an exception, catching it, and printing it:

```
try {
    X::AdHoc.new(payload => 'Stack').throw;
    CATCH { when X::AdHoc { .say; } }
}
```

Or, being a little lazier:

```
{
    die;
    CATCH { default { .say } }
}
```

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 11):

I actually found the answer while writing this question, and decided to post it here since it didn't show up in any of my previous searches. Perl 6's [Backtrace](https://docs.raku.org/type/Backtrace) class will get a stack trace and convert it to a string:

```
say "Stack: " ~ Backtrace.new;
```

(Use `Backtrace.new.full` to see some additional low-level stack frames which are normally hidden.)

Comment: @ChristopherBottoms That was it. `Backtrace.new.Str` gives the current stack trace as a string. Log it, store it, parse it. (But if you were parsing it, you wouldn't call `.Str`. You would access the `Backtrace` object's other methods.)

Comment: Oh, okay. You just want to check the stack trace at a particular place in your code without having to actually throw an exception.

Comment: @ChristopherBottoms Right, for example, to get a high level view of why a function is being called twice. Generally for debugging, not production logging.